# What are some words that can mean either pushing or dragging?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

I'm making a game in which the player can either push or drag certain objects, like crates.

In my code I usually refer to both of these actions as "moving" whenever I don't want to specify which one I'm talking about (for instance, if I need to write a function that checks whether an object is being pulled or dragged I'll call it is_object_being_moved).

There are, however, other reasons why an object might move other than the player pushing or dragging them, so I'd like to substitute all those instances of "move" for something more specific.

I thought about "lug", but it means "dragging or carrying" rather than "dragging or pushing". "Displace" or "transport" are still too general. "Budge" is more of a one-time burst of movement.

So can any of you think of a word that means both "to push" and "to drag"?

Comment: The dog pushed or dragged the pillow around the room: moved. I don't think there is anything else.

Comment: Seems you may be after the old “pull ‘n push”.

Comment: How about “to slide”: is _object_being_slid()  The dog slid the pillow around the room.

Comment: Questions about what to call functions are off-topic. But it seems some nice people have provided answers anyway.

Comment: @Jim, I really like slide, I'll probably end up using that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here are seven possibilities:

**shift, move, force, urge, propel, drive, impel**

Dictionary definitions are trivial to find online or elsewhere. For examples:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impel)
>
> Shift: *to move or to cause (something or someone) to move to a different place, position, etc*
> Move: *to change the place or position of*
> Urge: *to force or impel in an indicated direction or into motion or greater speed*
> Drive: *to impart a forward motion to by physical force*
> Propel: *to drive forward or onward by or as if by means of a force that imparts motion*
> Force: *to press, drive, pass, or effect against resistance or inertia*
> Impel: *to urge or drive forward*

Note that the force acting on something to move it may be imparted by a push or a pull; the effect on motion is the same

Comment: _Drive_ might have a slight push-bias but in my mind best reflects @carllacan's request. _Shift_ seems too passive?/shorter displacement, _urge_, _impel_, and _force_ is less strictly about displacement

Comment: Are these terms you would use? "The object is being driven." "Look at the player impel the object." I wouldn't (except shift and move).

Comment: Shift if used transitively seems active enough: "He shifted the rock". It can be used intransitively "the rock shifted" which doesn't imply someone moving it. So it might depend on details of context.